# More effective way to subdivide the cone?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

Was wondering what is the most effective/fast way to subdivide the cone to make the subsurf modifier work properly?

---

[image: Editing primitive]

Comment: I assume using a beveled edge on the base is not an option? One thing that comes to mind is making a cone from a cylinder, then you can add loop cuts easily. Once you are done you can remove doubles/merge the top vertices to remove the extras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do it I guess. Here's mine:
After adding a *cone* set it's *base fill type* to *triangle fan*. Select the lower edge and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel it and scroll the mouse to add two additional edges. Change the mode to *Percent* (press <kbd>M</kbd> tree times) and place the edges very near to each other. Next select the very upper edge and place it on top of the cone pressing <kbd>G</kbd> twice. Add a *subsurf modifier*.
[image]

Finally *dissolve* the edge at the bottom (<kbd>X</kbd>-->*Dissolve Edges*) and add the *edge loop* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to replace it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks!, handy to know, I was wondering that for a while and I should probably look up some more tutorials. which leads to another ( Kinda off topic ) question: `What software do you use for recording and splitting your gifs? Blender?`

Comment: For .gifs recording, please check out this topic: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 3):

1. Cone radius2 0.001!
2. Loop Cut.
3. Merge top vertices.

[image]

Comment: fantastic way to resolve the issue :)